# How can I override addTarget in a UITextField for only UIControlEvent.allEditingEvents?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uicontrolevents, addtarget

How can I override the `addTarget` function inside the `UITextField` class, but only for `UIControlEvent.allEditingEvents`?

The function is like this, however I am not sure how to apply it only for a specific control event.

```
override func addTarget(_ target: Any?, action: Selector, for controlEvents: UIControlEvents) {
    <#code#>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `super.addTarget` and only call your custom code if `controlEvents` equals to `.allEditingEvents`.

```
override func addTarget(_ target: Any?, action: Selector, for controlEvents: UIControlEvents) {
    super.addTarget(target, action: action, for: controlEvents)

    if controlEvents == .allEditingEvents {
        [your code]
    }
}
```